# Role of resistors in SCLK-CS-DI-DOUT lines in SD card circuit

Tags: pcb-design, circuit-design, spi, sd

hope everyone is safe and well.

I want to design a microSD card circuit. I searched for a reference design I noticed that they add a resistors in series in SCLK-CS-DI-DOUT lines.[Catalex-Micro-SD-Card-Module](https://file.vishnumaiea.in/hardware/micro-sd/Catalex-Micro-SD-Card-Module_1_LS.jpg)

My questions :

- why they are adding this resistors?
- How can I determine their values?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you planning to connect to a 3.3V MCU or 5V MCU? Nevertheless, I recommend not to use this circuit as a reference.

Comment: @Justme To a 3.3V MCU // STM32F767

Comment: For EMI noise reduction.

Comment: Since you are using a MCU with not just one, but two native SD host controllers that can be directly connected to card sockect, why even bother looking at badly designed SPI mode adapters?

Comment: Maybe some practical example, also important where the resistors have to be placed in order to reduce EMI and make it less susceptible to enviroment EMI : https://practicalee.com/spi/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resistors are added because the designer has no clue about how to design the circuit. They only make the circuit worse, limiting the data rate. 3k3 is far too high value to allow for useful SPI clock rates, so they are not simply for EMI noise reduction.

The most propable reason the resistors are drawn in the circuit is that the designer appears to think that the LVC125 that is used for 5V to 3.3V level conversion clamps the 5V input voltages to the 3.3V supply and the resistors are needed to limit the input clamping current. But it doesn't clamp to 3.3V. Even without resistors, the LVC125 will happily allow 5V input voltages when used with 3.3V supply voltage.

Since you have a 3.3V MCU with two native SD host interfaces and multiple SPI interfaces, you can simply connect the card directly (exact details would be in manufacturer hardware design notes).

Do not use this circuit as an example.

Answer (score 0):

The resistiors are to reduce the speed of the switching edge of the signals and by this reduce EMI. New MCUs have a Port configuration where you can change the strength of the MCU port. By this you do not need the serial termination resistors.

Comment: That would be the case if the resistors were like 33 or 330 ohms. But they are 3300 ohms which makes no sense as EMI preventing resistor. I consider it as an input slew rate violating resistor.

Comment: Not only are the values nonsense for EMI suppression, the resistors are in the wrong place - they're at the *receiving* end of the lines, not the driving end.  The one signal the board actually drives - the reply data - doesn't have one.  They provide no slew rate limitation for the jumper wires that would be what would actually radiate.

Comment: Not to mention other problems. Such as not having mandatory pull-ups for the unused SD card pins. And not having a voltage translation of the data out to the supplied voltage, as many 5V MCUs or other CMOS devices have minimum input high voltage over 3.3V.